# which type of component can be used in Visual C++

Tags: mfc, project, clr, atl, ocx

at this site

www.codejock.com

there are 2 suite, codejock suite pro and codejock toolkit pro; I want know if extreme suite pro can be used also in visual c++ project or only in visual basic 6 project; I know that there many type of component for visual c++ such as clr, atl, mfc, classic header .h  but don't know the difference. Moreover, in  many thread of stackoverflow, there are user that have asked of import of ocx control in visual c++ project. can you clarify me this doubts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to write in Visual C++ and especially MFC, use the Extreme Toolkit Pro.  They also bundle it into smaller packages if you only need some components.

Comment: ok, only mfc can be used in visual c++? Or I can use also activeX?

Comment: Can you is a different answer than should you. Visual C++ supports using ActiveX controls on dialogs, so theoretically, you can use the ActiveX toolkit.  But, if I was using Visual C++, I'd use the MFC version.  If I had to use the ActiveX version, then I'd use something else.

Comment: so you are telling me that in visual basic 6 I can use only activex (suite pro) while in visual c++ I can use both activex (suite pro) and MFC (toolkit pro) but with visual c++ MFC it's better...Is right?

Comment: can you answer me?

Comment: CodeJocks allows you to download eval editions.  Why don't you just download each one and see which one meets your needs.

Comment: Because I want know if ActiveX can be used in visual C++